# Backbone Collection and Multiple Subviews Design Issue

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Hi I have a design issue with backbone collections and subviews.

My problem is I have a  subview three levels down which needs a image collection that I pass from the parent view three levels up. 
I don't like this because it creates a chain of dependencies stemming from the parent view.

Currently, my image collection requires a business_id to generate the URL /business/the-biz-id/images. I pass the the collection down through subviews because I don't have the business_id globally available for rendered subviews.

Should I make the business_id globally available so subviews can instantiate collections without the business_id passed to it? I'm not sure if I should do this since global variable declarations could cause future problems if I forget about them. But, if it is available, I can avoid passing my image collection through several views.

How can I make the business_id available to subviews without making a global declaration? Suggestions? Opinions?

UPDATE 10/27/2013:

This is what I ended up using:

```
App.BusinessHelper = function (bizId) {
  var bizId = bizId;
  var obj = {};

  obj.getBizId = function () {
     return bizId;
  }

  App.BusinessHelper = obj;
}
```

I like this construction because the bizId can't be easily altered or changed. That said, I created myself a massive dependency on this object, but it was worth it in my situation for its convenience.

Comment: perhaps some code can help make your question more clear…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually i declare a global object like this.

```
var App = {};
```

and i attach things with it that i need to access globally. For example, in your case i attach `business_id` like below and access it wherever i need. You can't avoid these situations.

```
App.business_id = 15;
```

Comment: I will go with this answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add I'm going with this answer, not because it's the best, but because it fits the context of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make business_id global (which is most certainly a good idea), you can circumvent this by providing it to the views you instanciate when you create them.

```
var myView = new MyView({business_id: 10});
```

If `myView` is responsible for creating its subviews it's the way to go. The data you pass to the constructor is always providing context if your code architecutre is sane, ie. all things generic to views of the same type will be defined in the "class" declaration. Anything that depends on the context is provided as constructor parameters. Here business_id clearly is a piece of context.

As you probably know `business_id` will become available in the view as an attribute of `options`.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.subView = new SubView({
            business_id: this.options.business_id, 
            foo: 'bar'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I did not make my question more clear, but this is what I've been doing the whole time. Thank you for taking the time to answer though. I appreciate it.

Comment: This was, IMHO, the best approach.

Comment: I believe it depends on the context. In my case, I have a hierarchy of subviews that span several levels and only the last subview needs the business_id. I chose the other approach because I did not want to pass the business id through several intermediary subviews just so the last one can get it. Of course, there are trade offs to this method, but I believe I can live with them for the convenience and cleanliness of a globally accessible business_id.